# Who discovered the covering homomorphism between SU(2) and SO(3)?

Tags: mathematics, physics

Who discovered this? It is quite nontrivial and very important in quantum mechanics.

Comment: In old books on classical mechanics parametrization of $SO(3)$ by $SU(2)$ is called the Klein parametrization.

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11126/how-did-su2-came-into-physics/11127#11127

Answer (score 23):

Hamilton  and Klein, Klein was more explicit about it. [Hamilton in Lectures on Quaternions (1853)](https://archive.org/details/lecturesonquater00hami/page/n12) realized that his representation of rotations of rigid bodies by the unit quaternions was not $1$-$1$, but $2$-$1$. [Klein in Lectures on the Ikosahedron and the Solution of Equations
of the Fifth Degree (1888)](https://archive.org/details/cu31924059413439/page/n10) replaced the unit quaternions by $2 × 2$ unitary matrices with the determinant $1$, now denoted $SU(2)$. He then more or less spelled out that the unit quaternions and $SU(2)$ are isomorphic groups, which are $2$-$1$ epimorphic onto the group of 3D rotations $SO(3)$.

Pauli proposed the "*two-valuedness not describable classically*", which was later identified with the [electron spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#History), in 1924, and formalized it in the matrix form in 1927. In 1932 Heisenberg and Ivanenko guessed that the same effect regulates protons/neutrons as the states of a single particle, later dubbed nucleon, and incorporated it into their [proton–neutron model of the nucleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_of_the_neutron#Proton%E2%80%93neutron_model_of_the_nucleus).

[Steiner](https://academic.oup.com/philmat/article-abstract/17/1/1/1433907) cites this homomorphism as a prime example of "unreasonable effectiveness" of mathematics. Both times the mathematical machinery developed was not aimed, even indirectly, at the application it ended up being useful for. In the case of nucleus, any visible connection to rotations and 3D space is missing altogether.

Comment: But, in case of the isospin symmetry, it is not actually an exact symmetry of nature either.

Comment: Cayley should be also mentioned. He wrote on this much earlier than Hamilton and Klein.

Comment: Now that I have the points to *comment*, here is what I’d have been content to simply say: **No!** To answer "Hamilton and Klein" is to ignore swaths of well-documented history — and talk of Pauli, Heisenberg, etc., is besides the OP’s focused question. Less [anecdotally](https://xkcd.com/386/), the fact that this answer stood not only unquestioned, but heavily upvoted, praised as "fantastic" (a since-deleted comment) and likely soon "accepted", epitomizes (IMO) a systemic dysfunction of the site.

Comment: @ConsigliereZARF   In threads that "go viral", like this one, most people voting are non-regulars, they often value something more non-technical, expositional and accompanied by "fun facts". Even in regular threads, this is not an academic publication. But, I think, if you put the nuance and panoramic scope of your post into a more narrative form, it could be the one accepted eventually.

Comment: Exactly. And that's the dysfunction right there.

Comment: @ConsigliereZARF I hope that you decide to stay nonetheless. Viral threads are very rare, and regulars appreciate well-referenced comprehensive answers. In the end, the quality of the site depends on its users, and would benefit from a thorough user like yourself participating, it is the scarcity of them that creates the dysfunction. This is still a public resource though, so being a bit more expository helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking criticism with grace, but why would I? As far as I can tell, these users (capable of debating and moderating questions like this, *and* rooting out agenda-driven ones, a lot better) are at MO. Had professional historians flocked here, it could have been a place upholding the standards of both groups. But this never happened, and as it is, it upholds the standards of neither.

Comment: @ConsigliereZARF Because you can reach more people and educate them. Many historical questions will not be asked on MO, or read by people who might be put off by the highly technical level of the site. Posts here are not up to the level of historical scholarship, but, some of them at least, provide information and references beyond the common anecdotes floating on the web. It is not ideal, but we can improve on how things are, especially if more users like you join in.

Comment: @ConsigliereZARF It is usually easy to tell by how the question is written. But, in the grand scheme of things, it does not matter much what the OP agenda is, if there is a good answer others may appreciate it even if the OP doesn't. These posts will be up  for a long time, and it is better they come up than the usual google fare.

Comment: Note that I wrote 3 sentences. As to perennity, I wouldn't be so sure; unlike [MO](//meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/969/who-owns-mathoverflow), HSM is for-profit (and routinely deletes comment threads; 3, 2, 1,...)

Comment: @ConsigliereZARF I was talking about answers, they are almost never deleted. Comments are ideally for making answers better, and most people don't read them, I suspect.

Answer (score 18):

Before Hamilton (1847) one should cite Euler (1771), Gauss (1819), Rodrigues (1840), and Cayley (1845). Detailed references in e.g.

*Pujol, J.*, [**Hamilton, Rodrigues, Gauss, quaternions, and rotations: a historical reassessment**](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cma/1349803591), Commun. Math. Anal. 13, No. 2, 1-14 (2012). [ZBL1268.01010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1268.01010).

Specifically, to four numbers $p,q,r,s$ with $pp+qq+rr+ss=u$, [Euler](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6956m/f341.image) (1771, §33) attached

> [image]

which is precisely (the transpose of) the rotation attached to $(a,b,c,d)=\dfrac{(p,q,r,s)}{\sqrt u}$ in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Conversion_to_and_from_the_matrix_representation):
$$
R = \begin{pmatrix}
a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2&2bc-2ad        &2bd+2ac        \\
2bc+2ad        &a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2&2cd-2ab        \\
2bd-2ac        &2cd+2ab        &a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2\\
\end{pmatrix}.
\tag1
$$
So he had the *map*, though maybe not the group law on 4-tuples that makes it a *homomorphism*:<sup>1</sup> that (or less anachronistically, a "formula for the parameters of a composite rotation") is commonly attributed to [Rodrigues](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k163849/f416.image) (1840, p. 408), who put everything in the notation
$$
(a,b,c,d)=\left(\cos\tfrac\theta2,\ \sin\tfrac\theta2\cos g,\ \sin\tfrac\theta2\cos h,\ \sin\tfrac\theta2\cos l\right).
\tag2
$$
Then [Cayley](https://archive.org/details/collmathpapers01caylrich/page/n144) (1845, pp. 123-124) identified Rodrigues' multiplication of 4-tuples $(2)$ as quaternion multiplication, and the map $(a,b,c,d)\mapsto R$ as what we would call the adjoint representation of $\mathit{Sp}(1)$; and [Hamilton](https://archive.org/details/proceedingsofroy03proc/page/n30) (1847, pp. 13-14) concurred — as did also [Boole](https://archive.org/details/londonedinburghp33lond/page/279) (1848) and [Donkin](https://archive.org/details/londonedinburghp01maga/page/189) (1851).

One may wonder why Euler wasn't cited at the time. As far as I can tell, it's because [Monge](https://archive.org/details/TO00188449_1/page/99) (1786) had (ostensibly independently) published $(1)$ in the alternative notation 
$$
(a,b,c,d)=\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{M\vphantom Q}4},\sqrt{\tfrac{N\vphantom Q}4},\sqrt{\tfrac{P\vphantom Q}4},\sqrt{\tfrac{Q}4}\,\right),
\tag3
$$
and for many years everyone,<sup>2</sup> up to and including Rodrigues (p. 405), cited that instead. Only once Euler's paper was reprinted in a [book](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_K2JDAAAAcAAJ/page/n528) (1849, p. 440) did everyone<sup>3</sup> switch to citing him.

So far everything has been in terms of the sphere $S^3\subset\mathbb R^4$, or unit quaternions. If you want the homomorphism in terms of *literally*
$$
SU(2) =\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a+bi &-c+di\\c+di&\phantom{-}a-bi\end{pmatrix}: (a,b,c,d)\in S^3\right\},
\tag4
$$
the question becomes who first represented quaternions this way. The first memoirs on matrices by [Cayley](https://archive.org/details/collmathpapers02caylrich/page/n508) (1858), [Laguerre](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k433698b/f234.image) (1867), and [Frobenius](https://archive.org/details/journalfrdierei55crelgoog/page/n73) (1877) all mention the *possibility*, but apparently left it to be done explicitly by [Peirce](https://archive.org/details/circulars02univgoog/page/n192) (1882) and [four](https://archive.org/details/collectedmathema03jjsy/page/n658) [papers](https://archive.org/details/collectedmathema03jjsy/page/n662) [by](https://archive.org/details/collectedmathem04sylvrich/page/n161) [Sylvester](https://archive.org/details/collectedmathem04sylvrich/page/n168) (1882-83). On the other hand, one might argue that [Hermite](https://archive.org/details/journalfrdierei98crelgoog/page/n312) (1850, footnote) had it "before matrices", or ask who first identified rotations *of the (Riemann) sphere* as homographies $\smash{z\mapsto\frac{Az+B}{Cz+D}}$ with $\smash{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{smallmatrix}\right)}$ in $(4)$: for this, [Klein](https://archive.org/details/vorlesungenber00kleiuoft/page/34) clearly credits [Cayley](https://archive.org/details/collmathpapers10caylrich/page/n170) (1879).

Finally, as is often the case, it later emerged that unpublished papers of [Gauss](https://archive.org/details/werkearithmetiku08cfga/page/n360) (c.1819) already had both quaternion multiplication (p. 359) and rotations as homographies (p. 355).

---

<sup>1. Opinions differ: e.g. Cartan-Study (link below) say that Euler had the composition formula. Maybe they consider he'd have found it obvious, or thought of the *bijection* $\smash{\mathbb{RP}^3}\to SO(3)$ rather than the covering $\smash{S^3}\to SO(3)$, making the question moot; or they understand, better than I do, why his next § displayed a [4 x 4 array](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6956m/f343.image) which is very nearly a quaternion product: it is
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rr|rr}
p&-q&-r&-s\\
q&p&s&-r\\
\hline
r&-s&p&q\\
s&r&-q&p
\end{array}\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
1&\\
&-1\\
&&-1\\
&&&-1
\end{pmatrix}
\left(\begin{array}{rr|rr}
a&-b&-c&-d\\
b&a&d&-c\\
\hline
c&-d&a&b\\
d&c&-b&a
\end{array}\right).
\tag5
$$
(The first column of this array is right out of his [famous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_four-square_identity) [letter to Goldbach](https://archive.org/details/correspondancem01goldgoog/page/n608) (1748), and is also in his papers [E242](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6952c/f409.image) (1760) and [E445](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6953p/f266.image) (1773), as well as in [Lagrange](https://archive.org/details/uvresdelagrange03lagr/page/201) (1772), [Legendre](https://archive.org/details/essaitheorienomb00legerich/page/n229) (1797) and the English translation of his [Algebra](https://www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/16109634) (1810).)</sup>

<sup>2. E.g. [Monge](https://archive.org/details/histoiredelacad84hist/page/114) (1787), [Lacroix](https://archive.org/details/traitducalculdi02lacrgoog/page/n496) (1797), [Hachette](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_yJBY1_PahvUC/page/n275) (1813), [Encke](https://books.google.com/books?id=e-pEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA308#v=twopage) (1830), [Grunert](https://archive.org/details/journalfrdierei12crelgoog/page/n172) (1832), [Grunert](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_c6pEAAAAcAAJ/page/n491) (1833), [Cayley](https://archive.org/details/collmathpapers04caylrich/page/n578) (1862).</sup>

<sup>3. E.g. [Hamilton](https://archive.org/details/lecturesonquater1853hami/page/539) (1853), [Cayley](https://archive.org/details/collmathpapers02caylrich/page/n231) (1855), [Lebesgue](http://www.numdam.org/item/NAM_1856_1_15__403_0/) (1856), [Salmon](https://archive.org/details/higheralgebra00salmrich/page/36) (1866), [Hankel](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_bU9rkSdWlFAC/page/n209) (1867), [Hoüel](https://archive.org/details/thorielmentaire01hogoog/page/n246) (1874), [Jacobi](https://archive.org/details/gesammeltewerke03cgjj/page/n609) (1884), [Darboux](https://archive.org/details/leconsurlagendes01darbrich/page/n45) (1887), [Study](https://books.google.com/books?id=PCFMAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA350#v=twopage) (1890), [Beez](https://books.google.com/books?id=LN84AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA54&dq=Euler) (1896), [Koenigs](https://archive.org/details/cinematiqueprof00keonrich/page/n363) (1897), [Schoenflies](https://archive.org/details/encyklomath104encyrich/page/n227) (1902), [Cartan-Study](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k2440f/f236.image) (1908), [Müller](https://archive.org/details/encyklomath1103encyrich/page/n794) (1910), [Muir](https://archive.org/details/theoryofdetermin01muiruoft/page/305) (1911), [Whittaker](https://archive.org/details/treatisanalytdyn00whitrich/page/n25) (1917), [Bourbaki](https://books.google.com/books?id=csgswR8TlQ8C&pg=PA164).</sup>

Comment: Very very interesting.

Comment: I just read your exchanges with @Conifold. I understand both positions. I participate mainly to Math Stack Exchange. Yes, a small percentage of answers smell "amateurism" [consider that some of them come from High school "gifted students"]. IMHO, such sites participate to the evolution of education : they give the opportunity to non-yet-confirmed scientists to participate, to improve themselves by confronting their ideas/writing to other ones. Very scarcely, erroneous facts remain. This said, it is very important that experts [as you evidently are] participate to such sites.

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker Thanks for the kind words. It may or may not be important that they participate, but the ***fact*** is that (unlike at MO) they overwhelmingly don't; and it's getting worse, not better. My next to last comment in that thread tried to better explain why I think this is, but it's been deleted (not by me).